# VBA - How to check if a string variable/cell contains another string Variable?

Tags: string, vba, excel

basically, I need to find a way to check if a String variable contains another String variable(or preferably an item from an array). Here's my case:

I have a list of 15k+ Strings in Excel, and another one with 5k+ Strings.The Second list is composed of 3 character long abbreviations, and the first one might contain from 0 to 15 of those, separated by ", ". My goal is to count each occurrence, of each of those abbreviations.

I've approached this by creating an array containing all the abbreviations. Then I was hoping to loop through the 15k+ long list 5k+ times, to count the occurrences of each of those abbreviations, changing the abbreviation sought every loop. However I'm stuck with comparing the strings...

I've tried to use InStr to see if I get 0 or not. Although it worked for me before when I referred to a String being searched by variable, but it seems that expression sought can't be placed in such a way. I've been trying to use Find or Application.Match instead but had the same issue... I wonder if there is a VBA function I don't know about? Or maybe someone has an idea for a custom function or an entirely different approach? I've hit a brick wall...

Thank you in advance for any advice! I highly appreciate it.

Unfortunately I can't show you the data since it's customer's sensitive data but here's my loop:

```
With ActiveWorkbook
    For p = 1 To size
        For j = 6 To lrow
        a = .Sheets("Server View").Cells(j, 3).Value
        tmp = Apps(p)
        test = InStr(1, a, tmp)

            If test = 0 Then
            Else
                b = .Sheets("Server View").Cells(j, 9).Value
                If b = PROD Then
                    cval = .Sheets("temp").Cells(j, 3).Value
                    cval = cval + 1
                    .Sheets("temp").Cells(j, 3).Value = cval
                Else
                    cval = .Sheets("temp").Cells(j, 2).Value
                    cval = cval + 1
                    .Sheets("temp").Cells(j, 2).Value = cval
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next p
End With
```

Comment: Show what you've tried please.  Code is better than a long description.

Comment: And perhaps a screenshot of a small sample of data?

Comment: And any error messages

Comment: what is PROD please?

Comment: PROD is just a value from another column, occurrences of which I have to count as well. Basically the only thing important there is this line:

test = InStr(1, a, tmp)

Comment: I think we need to have an idea of what is in variable a and in temp for a given case you would expect to find a match on.  I can for example do the following and it returns found:  a = "abcde"

    apps = Array("abc", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")
   
    temp = apps(0)
    
    If InStr(1, a, temp, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then Debug.Print "Found"

Comment: It worked! that's exactly what I needed! wasn't aware that vbTextCompare is required. Anyways, Thanks a lot for such a quick and precise response.